# UI-view not changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I making application in Ruby on Rails and using AngularJS. 
My application.js file is

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require angular.min
//= require angular-ui-router.min


var app = angular.module("railsApp", ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })
        .state('about', {
            url: 'about',
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});

app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.helloMsg = "Hello from test application";
});
```

index page

```
<h1>Welcome#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>

{{helloMsg}}<br>
<ui-view></ui-view>

<a ui-sref="about">about</a>
```

when index page loaded I see message "Hello from test application" and into `<ui-view></ui-view>` substituted template content, but I clicked about link new template is not loading and url not changed to /about. what is the problem? Thanks and Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this will fix your URL issue and renders the requested views.You have to give perfect URL
so that view will be mathced perfactly.

```
var app = angular.module("railsApp", ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })
        .state('/about', {
            url: 'about',
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Comment: ahhh... beat me by seconds :)

Comment: Thank you very much, your advice has helped to correct the problem!

Comment: correct config is `var app = angular.module("railsApp", ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});

app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.helloMsg = "Hello from test application";
});`

Answer (score 0):

as per the [ui router readme](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/README.md), try to change `url: 'about' to`url: '/about'